# google map android white map no map?

Tags: android, google-maps

google map android white map no map?

I test it on emulator, it works fine, but deploy on real samsung tab s2, it only show white map?

I have try million way, still do not find why.

Answer (score 0):

The real cause is wi-fi connection accidently lost, I did not realize it. 
That is why the samsung tab show white map.